# Conversion between wchar_t char in ANSI Code Page

Tags: c++, unicode, char, wchar

If I am in the ANSI codepage only environment.

Does this conversion `wide char` to `char`:

```
char ansi_cstr[size_of_ansi_str];
WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, ansi_wstr.c_str(), -1, ansi_str, size_of_ansi_str, 0, 0);
std::string ansi_str = std::string(ansi_cstr);
```

equal to following

```
std::string ansi_str = std::string(ansi_wstr.begin(), ansi_wstr.end());
```

and `char` to `wide char`

```
wchar_t ansi_wcstr[size_of_ansi_str];
MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, ansi_str.c_str(), -1, ansi_wcstr, size_of_ansi_str);
std::wstring ansi_wstr = std::wstring(ansi_wcstr);
```

equal to

```
std::wstring ansi_wstr = std::wstring(ansi_str.begin(), ansi_str.end());
```

Are these two cases remain the same behavior in the ansi codepage only environment?

Comment: The real question is *why* would you be using ANSI code pages in the year 2014?

Comment: Even worse: a  ANSI codepage **only** environment. I think the first Windows which had Unicode support (via Unicows) was Windows 95, so this would be Windows 3.1 from 1994. 20 years old. Talking about legacy development. Then again, we still see Turbo C++ questions around here.

Comment: Windows 95/98/ME were an Ansi-based OS. UCS-2 was used in NT4, and then replaced with UTF-16 in Windows 2000. The two product lines were not merged together into a single Unicode OS until XP.

Comment: @CodyGray Maybe because, even in 2018, so many shapefiles' DBFs still use 0x57 Language Driver ID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no such thing as **the** ANSI code page environment. There are dozens.

Your two "shortcut" conversions are incorrect in all of them.

The conversion from **ASCII** char to UTF-16 `wchar_t` would work with your last method, but this fails with the second half of most ANSI code pages. It works best with the Western European code page, where it gets ~only 32 characters wrong. For instance. the Euro sign € will always be mis-converted.

Answer (score 1):

> WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, ansi_wstr.c_str(), -1, ansi_str, size_of_ansi_str, 0, 0);

**IS NOT** the same as

> std::string ansi_str = std::string(ansi_wstr.begin(), ansi_wstr.end());

`WideCharToMultiByte()` performs a real conversion from UTF-16 to ANSI using the codepage that `CP_ACP` refers to on that PC (which can be different on each PC based to user locale settings).  `std::string(begin, end)` merely loops through the source container type-casting each element to `char` and does not perform any codepage conversion at all.

Likewise:

> MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, ansi_str.c_str(), -1, ansi_wcstr, size_of_ansi_str);

**IS NOT** the same as

> std::wstring ansi_wstr = std::wstring(ansi_str.begin(), ansi_str.end());

For the same reason.  `MultiByteToWideChar()` performs a real conversion from ANSI to UTF-16 using the `CP_ACP` codepage, whereas `std::wstring(begin, end)` simply type-casts the source elements to `wchar_t` without any conversion at all.

The type-casts would be *equivelent* to the API conversions ONLY if the source strings are using ASCII characters in the `0x00-0x7F` range.  But if they are using non-ASCII characters, all bets are off.